# Current has not been initialized. You must initialize Current before trying to read it

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, publishing-site

After I publishing my website and run it from IIS, I face a problem.

"**Current has not been initialized. You must initialize Current before trying to read it.**"

I used Umbraco version 4.11.1

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have possibly have DLLs in the live bin folder that shouldn't be there. Delete the bin folder and replace with the upgraded bin folder. It is more than likely the global DLL causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.But I solved the problem. I added Global.asax to the root of the IIS website and everything was okay.

Comment: I wouldn't usually suggest unmarking my answer, but it wasn't what was causing the issue, so can't really be marked as correct. You should add your own answer and mark that as correct so that people know in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Application Pools and Recycle Site site Application pools.